Logging GraphQLErrors in Datadog
I am trying to implement some logging for my api that is using graphql.
When logging errors however most third party monitoring tools (I am using datadog) don't capture graphql errors and the stacktrace.
I could put that information into a separate object, however then the minified code would not get sourced by my source maps.
Looking for any ideas, I thought perhaps there could be a way to convert GraphQLErrors to an Error since it looks like it's extending the Error class. (Source: https://github.com/graphql/graphql-js/blob/16.x.x/src/error/GraphQLError.ts)
